# Using ssh inside a script to run another script that itself calls ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to write a script that builds a list of nodes then ssh into the first node of that list 
and runs a checknodes.sh script which it's self is just a for i loop that calls checknode.sh

The first 2 lines seems to work ok, the list builds successfully, but then I get either get just the echo line of checknodes.sh to print out or an error saying *cat: gpcnodes.txt: No such file or directory*

MYSCRIPT.sh:

```
#gets the master node for the job
MASTERNODE=`qstat -t -u \* | grep $1 | awk '{print$8}' | cut -d'@' -f 2 | cut -d'.' -f 1 | sed -e 's/$/.com/' | head -n 1`
#builds list of nodes in job
ssh -qt $MASTERNODE "qstat -t -u \* | grep $1 | awk '{print$8}' | cut -d'@' -f 2 | cut -d'.' -f 1 | sed -e 's/$/.com/'  > /users/issues/slow_job_starts/gpcnodes.txt"

ssh -qt $MASTERNODE cd /users/issues/slow_job_starts/
ssh -qt $MASTERNODE /users/issues/slow_job_starts/checknodes.sh
```

checknodes.sh

```
for i in `cat gpcnodes.txt `
do 
    echo "### $i ###"
    ssh -qt $i /users/issues/slow_job_starts/checknode.sh
done
```

checknode.sh

```
str=`hostname`
cd /tmp
time perf record qhost >/dev/null 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/${str}/'
perf report  --pretty=raw | grep % | head -20 | grep -c kernel.kallsyms | sed -e "s/^/`hostname`:/"
```

Comment: You should search for Paramiko... it will make SSHing between various machines/running remote commands a breeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ssh -qt $MASTERNODE cd /users/issues/slow_job_starts/` is finished, the changed directory is lost.
With the backquotes replaced by `$(..)` (not an error here, but get used to it), the script would be something like

```
for i in $(cat /users/issues/slow_job_starts/gpcnodes.txt)
do 
    echo "### $i ###"
    ssh -nqt $i /users/issues/slow_job_starts/checknode.sh
done
```

or better

```
while read -r i; do 
    echo "### $i ###"
    ssh -nqt $i /users/issues/slow_job_starts/checknode.sh
done < /users/issues/slow_job_starts/gpcnodes.txt
```

Perhaps you would also like to change your last script (start with `cd /users/issues/slow_job_starts`)

You will find more problems, like `sed -e 's/^/${str}/'` (the `${str}` inside single quotes won't be replaced by a host), but this should get you started.

EDIT:
I added option `-n` to the `ssh` call.
Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin).
Without this option only one node is checked.

Comment: afaik `ssh` eats/slurps `stdin` (this is what I remember from my ssh scripts) , a work around is to use a different `fd`.

Comment: @Jetchisel Thanks, I added the option `-n`.